# How to avoid Permission denied (publickey) when pulling from github?

Tags: github, ssh

I want to connect with GitHub from my server Centos.

I was doing `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and these problem solved.

But, I don't know why, when I am sign out and then sign in again, the problem shows again.
Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check exactly what key is used with:

```
git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -Tv" pull
```

That way, you will see which URL and key is actually used by your command, and have some clue as to why the current key does not work.

Note that `ssh-add` is only valid for your current session: signing out/back in would require an `ssh-add` again. Which is why it is generally part of your `.bashrc` to automate that step.

Comment: sorry, but when I use `git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -Tv"` pull, I stiil get Permission denied. Could you explain to me, how to automate these step using .bashrc?

Comment: @wowothk The goal was not to avoid the error message, but to get some more verbose logs from SSH

Comment: @wowothk You can use https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows (for Windows initially, but can be used in your Linux session as well)

Comment: thanks for your insight, now I can understand the concept